# Numpy correlate

Tags: python, numpy

I've two signals stored in a 1D array `a` and `b` that I'd like to correlate. For that I've tried

```
corr=np.correlate(a,b, mode='full')
```

and I get this error:

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

I've checked the shape of the two arrays:

```
>>> a.shape
(1, 10501)
>>> b.shape
(1, 10501)
```

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks as if `np.correlate` expects the vectors to be flat. You can use `np.ravel` to convert your vectors to flat vectors.

Comment: Expanding on @cel's comment: if the shape of `a` is `(1, 10501)`, then, as far as numpy is concerned, it is not a 1D array.  It is a 2D array, with a first dimension of length 1.  You can use `np.ravel`, or the method `a.ravel()`, to "flatten" the array into a 1D array with shape `(10501,)`.